# Ordenar los archivos de este directorio alfabéticamente

Tags: php, array, archivo

tengo este código en php, el cual me muestra los archivos y carpetas que hay en una carpeta que pasamos por parámetro, el problema es que me los muestra desordenados, mi idea era crear un array de arrays donde guardar el nombre del archivo y el de la carpeta, de esta manera:
***Se que el formato, no es el adecuado, *es solo un ejemplo****

```
./practicas{
            ./M07{
                   pt1.php,
                   pt2.php}
             ./M08{
                   pt1.php,
                   pt2.php,
                   pt3.php}}
```

La cosa es que cuando sale del while me borra el array: aquí muestro una IMG de como se ve el resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a continuación dejo mi código:

```
    <?php
//mostramos los archivos que hay en la carpeta /home/clase/M07/

include './comun/connexion.php';
include './comun/errores.php';
include './comun/validate.php';  

$array = [];
$carpeta = "";


function archivos($ruta, $carpeta, $array){
    

    if (is_dir($ruta)){
        // Abre un gestor de directorios para la ruta indicada
        $gestor = opendir($ruta);
        echo "<ul>";

        // Recorre todos los elementos del directorio
        while (($archivo = readdir($gestor)) !== false)  {
            $ruta_completa = $ruta . "/" . $archivo;
                echo "<br>";
            // Se muestran todos los archivos y carpetas excepto "." y ".."
            if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
                // Si es un directorio se recorre recursivamente
                if (is_dir($ruta_completa)) {

                    echo "<spam>" . $archivo . "</spam>";
                    $carpeta= $archivo;
                    $array[$carpeta] = [];
                    echo("<br>0". var_dump($array)."<br>");
                    archivos($ruta_completa, $carpeta, $array);
                } else {
                    
                    array_push($array[$carpeta], $archivo);
                    echo("<br>1". var_dump($array)."<br>");
                    
                    $extension = pathinfo($ruta_completa, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if ($extension == "php" || $extension == "html") {
                        echo "<a href='".$ruta_completa."' target='_blank'>" . $archivo . "</a>";
                    }else{
                    //si es un archivo se haraun a etiqueta que lo descargue
                    
                    echo "<a href='".$ruta_completa."' download='".$archivo."'>" . $archivo . "</a>";
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        echo("<br>2". var_dump($array)."<br>");
        closedir($gestor);
        echo "</ul>";
    } else {
        echo "No es una ruta de directorio valida<br/>";
    }
    echo("<br>3". var_dump($array)."<br>");
    return $array;
}



$ruta = "./practicas";

$array = archivos($ruta, $carpeta , $array);

echo "<br>Array al final :". var_dump($array)."<br>";
```

Para no causar problemas y aclarar:

***Mi problema:*** se muestran los nombres de los archivos desordenados y me gustaría que se,
mostraran ordenados, no se si hay alguna manera de mostrarlos directamente sin meterlos en
un array, con alguna función o si es mejor seguir mi lógica de meterlos en un array,
después ordenar esta array y mostrarlos ordenados

Comment: Quizás me perdí, pero yo los veo ordenados

Comment: Si te fijas sale 1,10,11,2,3,….    La idea sería 1,2,3,….,10,11

Comment: Pero es que así se ordenan los nombres de los archivos. porque se ordenan como string. Si te fijas en el explorador de archivos en windows veras que tendrá el mismo orden,.

Comment: @Yussef  esa es mi consulta si hay manera de ordenarlos de mayor a menor , para que en lugar de parecer un explorador, quede como una lista ordenada

Comment: @Yussef y no sé de qué manera mostrártelo, ya que en la pregunta queda un poco raro, pero mi explorador lo ordena  de mayor a menor

Comment: estoy casi seguro que el array esta vacio por algun motivo... creo que va por aqui: `$array[$carpeta] = [];`

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 si que puede ser que sea eso, pero solo se ejecuta cuando el  parámetro que lee es un directorio y no un archivo, no? 
Al menos esa era mi lógica inicial XD

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 a parte en la imagen si te fijas, me muestra el array como quiero, pero cuando sale del while se "borra"

Comment: quiero darte una respuesta pero creo que voy a demorar ... la verdad deberias implementar recursion... estare aqui en 7 horas creo ... que tengas buenas dia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ocupar "Natural Sort" (["natsort"](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.natsort.php#)), que es el nombre que se le da al ordenamiento alfanumérico que hacemos los humanos

```
natsort(archivos($ruta, $carpeta , $array));
```

Comment: me di cuenta que mi función me devuelve un array vacío... pero antes de probar tu solución... en cuanto resuelva ese problema mirto tu solución, gracias

Comment: Buena respuesta.